Is there any research or theory that indicates whether smelling isopropyl alcohol can be a safe treatment for regularly recurring nausea?
I have seen research papers that have found that smelling isopropyl alcohol is a safe and effective treatment for nausea in Emergency Room patients.
https://www.cfp.ca/content/64/8/580#:~:text=Two%20trials%20with%20about%20200%20nonpregnant%20adults%20presenting,inhaled%20isopropyl%20alcohol%20versus%2040%20with%20oral%20ondansetron.
Some patients suffer regularly with nausea, due to side effects of medicines, motion sickness or other causes.
Is there any research or theory that indicates whether isopropyl alcohol is a safe way to regularly treat nausea in such people? Is there a recommended maximum frequency of use to avoid harm from the isopropyl alcohol?

Proving a negative is exhausting if not impossible. I couldn't find any such studies; studies using isopropyl alcohol (IPA) are largely about short term use situations, such as postoperative nausea, and certainly not problems like motion sickness. (This meta analysis concluded the evidence in most papers reviewed is of limited quality.) Look rather for papers on the safety of inhaled IPA. I've been taught that IPA inhalation should be avoided if possible, but that's not proof of anything either way.

@anongoodnurse Thank you I will search for such papers.

When I first saw this question I thought it sounded borderline insane. Who would inhale isopropyl alcohol?! But then I read the link and realized they're only smelling the alcohol, not inhaling the liquid into their lungs. I found the word "inhale" to be very misleading, so I edited the question to clarify. If you disagree with my edits, you can revert them.

@CareyGregory Your edit is fine. It had not occurred to me that my sentence might have been interpreted as inhaling the liquid rather than just breathing in some of the vapour.

Fwiw, I found two more meta analyses, one showing no greater effect than placebo, the other a modest effect. All the studies I've read conclude "more studies are needed."
